# Is there holomorphic function $g$ on the open disk such that $g(e^{i a}) =\sin{a}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Can we find a holomorphic function $g$ on the open unit disk and continuous on the closed unit disk such that $g(e^{i a})=\sin(a)$ for all real numbers $a$?

it seems it is not true, but I couldn't have an argument to prove it or a counterexample to disprove it.

Comment: That argument isn't correct: note that the same argument would show that any function that's real on the real axis "can't be holomorphic, because Im$(g)=0$ on the real axis". Derivatives (and equations involving them) need open sets to be defined, while the unit circle is not open in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @GregMartin, so the statement is true and need to be proven, right?

Comment: Well, $g(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(z+z^{-1}\right),$ works, but that has a pole at $0.$ But it still seems to contradict your argument.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, so is the statement true or false?

Comment: @math_for_ever I don’t know.

Comment: The values of a holomorphic function on the open disk are uniquely determined by its values on the perimeter. Meaning that $\frac1{2i}(z+z^{-1})$ is the only possibility. But that has a pole.

Comment: I got it backwards, and @JyrkiLahtonen repeated my error. The function should be $g(z)=\frac1{2i}(z-z^{-1}).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I copied it from you. The idea is that matters :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given such a $g,$ and let $\gamma(t)=re^{it}$ for $t \in[0,2\pi],$ for $0<r<1.$ Then:

$$\int_{\gamma} g(z)\,dz = 0$$

because $g$ has no poles inside $\gamma.$

But as $r\to 1^-,$ these integrals converge to:

$$i\int_0^{2\pi}g(e^{it})e^{it}\,dt$$

So if $g(e^{it})=\sin t$ then this limit is equal to:

$$i\int_0^{2\pi}\sin t(\cos t+i\sin t)\,dt$$

Which is equal to: $$-\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2 t\,dt=-\pi$$ which is not zero.

So $g$ cannot exist without a pole.

And, indeed, $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2i}\left(z-z^{-1}\right)\,dz = -\pi.$$

Comment: In the first line the $f$ should be a $g$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo yep, thanks.